# What struggles would a ten-foot tall humanoid face in daily life?

Tags: biology, fantasy-races, sea-creatures

In the story I am creating the fantasy race I am creating is roughly 10-20 feet tall from the tip of their ears to the end of their tail in water, and out of water 8-10 foot tall from tip of their ears to the bottom of their feet. But lately in the story they are going to the humans' areas regularly and spending more time on land. The humans in this world are just like normal humans and are 5-6 foot tall.

Here is some information on the fantasy race if you need it:

- They are mostly bipedal, have scales covering all over, and live all throughout the Atlantic and Pacific Ocean, also the Antarctic Ocean but that has a population under 1 million.
- Those who live closer to shore have darker skin (In many colors, mainly green and blue but also come in pink, yellow, orange, red and such). But those that live in the trenches have very light to almost white skin...well more so very thin scales.
- They also have toxic barbs at the side of their feet, that can leave a blue whale unconscious for 1 hour. And Talons that have grips on them to hold on to their pray.
- They hunt in small family groups and bring back whatever they catch back to their town. (Towns have roughly 100,000+ individuals at any given time and send out multiple hunting parties a week).
- They can go one month max without food, before they slowly die within a few weeks to starvation, though they prefer to eat daily, about on to two meals a day, but if needed (food shortage) they can happily go on week with a few meals.
- They have at least 4 eggs a clutch and 2 of four die due to a common childhood disease that makes their gills constrict to the point no air gets to their lungs. Families normally have 10 clutches on average. The eggs have a very thin and somewhat flexible shell that is easily broken with cornered objects.
- Around 8/10 children who don't get the deadly disease (that I mentioned earlier) reach age 18 and roughly 6/10 of those live long enough to reproduce on their own.
- Tiger like stripes on the face or arms are favorable in partners due to it being a sign of high fertility — Except for the Trench subspecies since they're partially blind (to the point they only see the outlines of shapes and features and mainly focus on smell).
- The trench subspecies mainly focus on the smell of their partners, for feminine genders it's favorable to have a sweet scent, for masculine genders its favorable to have an ash and sulfuric scent.
- Most Trench Subdominants are lower in society and work in ore/coal mines that are manufactured into goods and traded with other seafolk and sold within the shops and higher cities. As a result, these subdominants are greatly valued in the society but highly looked down upon and scoffed at their needs by many emperors. So, they often get whatever trickles down to the depths of society (Hehe see what I did there). So they get a lot less food and resources than the higher ups.
- They tend to weigh 400 pounds on average and be 10 foot tall. Their lifespan is up to 3000 years at max, average is 2000. (20 human years= 1 subdominant year).

Comment: What is the gravity level on this planet? Pandora, for example had lower gravity.

Comment: they have slightly less gravity than our world and their bone structure is made of cartilage not real bone.

Comment: (a) I converted your wall-of-text post to something readable. (b) Most of your description isn't relevant to the question. (c) This is a prohibited open-ended brainstorming question (see [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]). Can you convert this from an off-topic [infinite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6139/40609) to an on-topic [finite list of things](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6138/40609)?

Comment: You should read HG Wells. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Food_of_the_Gods_and_How_It_Came_to_Earth

Comment: @Author Arian  If thier skeltons are made of  cartilage instead of bone they might not be able to stand up on land.  And if they lie down on land they might be crushed by their body weight and die.

Answer (score 14):

**Starvation.**

/Towns have roughly 100,000+ individuals at any given time and send out multiple hunting parties a week)/

This is 100,000 individuals in a fixed location that sustain themselves by hunting whatever wanders into the vicinity of that location.  100,000 very large individuals.  The area will be depleted of prey items, fast.

100,000 individuals of that size will need to keep moving regardless of what they eat.  100,000 herbivores or filter feeders will also exhaust the area very quickly.

100,000 in a fixed location must be supported by a large area dedicated to producing food for the 100,000 individuals, regardless of what the food is.  Unless they were photosynthetic.  You could have a town sized forest with 100,000 trees.

Comment: The ones in the tropics are partly but they can't produce all of the energy they need that way, and they do tend to trade for a lot of their food with other towns or other nations. The areas (Excluding the towns in Antarctica) are very plentiful in their marine life and they have an extremely varied diet (excluding the trench subspecies), and have their own farms and are omnivores, though their diet consists of 70% meat and 30% plants. They tend to hunt whales whenever they can. (The trench subspecies hunts giant squid regularly though they have to hunt in larger numbers because their blindne-

Comment: blindness tends to leave them at a disadvantage, due to being outweighed (side note they also hunt Colossal Squids that would normally feet one of them for 4 to 3 days or longer.) and when they come to the surface, due not being able to hunt as well as others. Also, they have a more flexible bone structure than tropics due to the high pressure from the zones above, so they are not the best at walking or simple tasks when they are not in their natural environment. Also, they tend to (in desperate cases) eat whatever they can find that are near the oceanic vents.

Comment: What I'm hearing is that in this world, whales and colossal squids are going to go extinct. If 5ft tall humans exterminated terrestrial megafauna, your lizards are going to do the same thing for aquatic.

Answer (score 5):

I assume they will swim horizontally in the water. If so, then upright walking will cause their hearts to have some problem against gravity. Instead of pushing/pulling blood from several inches high, it will start pushing blood a few feets high and pulling from 6 feet. Obviously they will not be perfectly horizontal in water but staying upright for a long time will be an issue for them. I am not sure if possible but a circular blood system will reduce/remove this strain.

Comment: What's a circular blood system? All I'm getting is cross posts for circulatory system

Comment: I don't quite see how giraffes manage this and why the new "human-ish" people wouldn't be able to.

Comment: @ZizyArcher Giraffes spend their whole lives upright, with hearts that push the blood that way all the time. These creatures wouldn't.

Comment: @Zephyr Giraffes _don't_ spend their whole lives upright, and without some clever engineering, there would be a pressure change in their head of about one atmosphere when they bend down to drink.  I don't know how they manage it, but it is possible.

Comment: They swim horizontally if they need to get to areas quicker or need to maneuver over tight corners.  but for the most part they swim vertically.

Comment: @AuthorArian You can swing away the circulatory problem but they *should* swim horizontally. Air has very little resistance compared to water, in water minimizing drag is crucial. No animal will evolve to predominantly move vertically. Even we prefer to swim horizontally. Walking submerged in water is very very difficult.